# Pandas.DataFrame and display.max_columns (bug?)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a situation that i don't understand and the docs didn't help me.

I'm reading the first row of a TXT file with read_fwf, then i convert that DataFrame to Str so i can identify the number of occurrences of the word "MAZDA" and return the indexes of each word.

Also i'm using the `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)` so i can see all the string printed in the console.

So, with this code all works fine:

```
def read_MazdaSource(self, file_path):
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

    self.data = pd.read_fwf(file_path, nrows=1, header=None)

    dataFrameStrNew = self.data[0].to_string().strip()

    mazdaOcur = [s.start() for s in re.finditer('MAZDA', dataFrameStrNew)]

    print(mazdaOcur)
    print(dataFrameStrNew)
```

And the Output:

> ```
> [43, 61]
> 0    US999999075616686995037420CONTINENTAL MAZDA             MAZDA0000 OLD SEWARD HIGHWAY
> ```

Everything's good here, but if i remove the `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)` the code won't work, the output is the following:

> [43]  0    US999999075616686995037420CONTINENTAL MAZDA   ...

Why Pandas is "reading" the string as it looks in the console and not the real information of the string?

Python: 3.8

Pandas: 1.1.2

PyCharm Run Time Version: 11.0.8

PyCharm: 2020.2.3 (Community Edition)

Regards

Diego

Comment: Please update the question to make the example reproducible for those who want to help you.

Comment: You're right, i will update....

Answer (score 0):

pandas is working fine, the line

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```

just changes how the data are displayed when you print them

Comment: Precisely, i don't understand why changes the way it takes the variable data.

Comment: @DiegoDuarte what happens exactly? your question says that it doesn't work but what does that mean? what's the error? if it's just the print output then that's intended